# True tablespace size in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, space, tablespace

I need to know *true* tablespace size in Oracle. I have some tablespace and I need to know how many space it uses now and how many space is free (and maybe percent of free space). I found in web some sqls but all of them showed size based on water mark... which is not true space allocated now but as far as I know the highest value which has ever been reached... 
So my real need is to know if I have enough space for my data which constantly are written and I must know how much of them I can store before having to delete some of them.

Thanks

Answer (score 19):

Try this:

```
-- Available space, by tablespace

SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT tablespace_name FROM dba_tablespaces)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes) AS total_bytes
     FROM dba_data_files
     GROUP BY tablespace_name)
  USING (tablespace_name)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT tablespace_name, sum(bytes) AS used_bytes
     from dba_segments
     GROUP BY tablespace_name)
  USING (tablespace_name)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT tablespace_name, SUM(bytes) AS free_bytes
     FROM dba_free_space
     GROUP BY tablespace_name)
  USING (tablespace_name);
```

Comment: Thanks very much!!!
I can confirm that it works :)
Maybe I should register and vote for your answer because it solves problem which I found very tough for many people and which has not good answer in web... now it has :)

Comment: Note that if any datafiles are set to autoextend and the files are not at their maximum size then this answer does not pick that up. It reports on free space in the current allocation only.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to get an idea of data file size including those files that can auto extend then try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.tablespace_name,
            sum(a.bytes)/1024/1024 CurMb,
            sum(decode(b.maxextend, null, a.bytes/1024/1024, b.maxextend*(SELECT value FROM v$parameter WHERE name='db_block_size')/1024/1024)) MaxMb,
            round(100*(sum(a.bytes)/1024/1024 - round(c.free/1024/1024))/(sum(decode(b.maxextend, null, a.bytes/1024/1024, b.maxextend*(SELECT value FROM v$parameter WHERE name='db_block_size')/1024/1024)))) UPercent,
            (sum(a.bytes)/1024/1024 - round(c.free/1024/1024)) TotalUsed,
            (sum(decode(b.maxextend, null, a.bytes/1024/1024, b.maxextend*(SELECT value FROM v$parameter WHERE name='db_block_size')/1024/1024)) - (sum(a.bytes)/1024/1024 - round(c.Free/1024/1024))) TotalFree 
FROM dba_data_files a,
   sys.filext$ b,
   (SELECT d.tablespace_name , sum(nvl(c.bytes,0)) free
     FROM dba_tablespaces d,dba_free_space c
     WHERE d.tablespace_name = c.tablespace_name(+) 
     GROUP BY d.tablespace_name) c
WHERE a.file_id = b.file#(+)
    AND a.tablespace_name = c.tablespace_name  
GROUP BY a.tablespace_name,
       c.free/1024
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this would assist you,

```
 SELECT a.tablespace_name, a.file_name, a.bytes allocated_bytes,b.free_bytes FROM dba_data_files a,
(SELECT file_id, SUM(bytes) free_bytes FROM dba_free_space b GROUP BY file_id) b WHERE a.file_id=b.file_id
ORDER BY a.tablespace_name;
```