# Oracle: how to check space used by a tablespace when no dba privs

Tags: oracle, space, tablespace

I need to check space used by a tablespace but I have no dba privs.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Ask your DBA for the same.

Comment: If you can select from the DBA_ views (which don't require "DBA privileges", just access to the appropriate views) you can use the SQL from my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207122/true-tablespace-size-in-oracle/2207140#2207140). Best of luck.

Comment: can't ask DBA at moment

Comment: don't have access to DBA_ views

Comment: Not really. The DBA_ views rely on system tables which are not directly accessible - for example, the DBA_DATA_FILES view reads from a table (or perhaps view?) named `x$kccfe` which at a guess might contain datafile extent information - but I can't select directly from it. Thus, even if someone picked apart the DBA_ views it's likely that the resultant SELECT wouldn't execute. So if you want to know what space is available in a tablespace you either A) need to get access to the DBA_ views, or B) ask someone with the requisite privileges for the information. Best of luck.

Comment: If you can see the server, maybe you can see the size of the datafiles (.dbf) that make up the tablespace. They should have a fairly similar name, but there may be more than one file per tablespace. As mentioned above if you don't have dba privs you can't access the tablespace information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately without explicit permissions to the `dba_free_space` or `dba_segments` views you are stuck with your users default tablespace:

```
SELECT
  ts.tablespace_name,
  TO_CHAR(SUM(NVL(fs.bytes,0))/1024/1024, '99,999,990.99') AS MB_FREE
FROM
  user_free_space fs,
  user_tablespaces ts,
  user_users us
WHERE
  fs.tablespace_name(+)   = ts.tablespace_name
AND ts.tablespace_name(+) = us.default_tablespace
GROUP BY
  ts.tablespace_name;
```

If you need to check the size of a tablespace for which you don't have a user with that as their default tablespace you're stuck with going back to your DBA.
Test with the system tablespace as default:
[image]
Test with an app tablespace as the default tablespace:
[image]
This schema does not have query on the dba views:

```
select * from dba_free_space;
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 13 Column: 15
```

Comment: Why the column is called 'MB_FREE', shouldn't it be spaced used?