# PL SQL - Recover a user's volume from my tablespace

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to recover the volume that a user uses in my database. But I can not find how to do it.
Here is my code:

```
FUNCTION EspaceUtilise (v_user IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NVARCHAR2 AS requetes NVARCHAR2(4000);
  BEGIN
    DECLARE
        unused_bytes NUMBER;        
        total_bytes NUMBER;
        CURSOR c_infosUser IS SELECT * FROM all_users where USER_ID = v_user;
        v_rqt NVARCHAR2(4000);
    BEGIN
      OPEN c_infosUser;
      FETCH c_infosUser INTO v_rqt;
      WHILE c_infosUser%FOUND LOOP
        -- Get user volume here 
      FETCH c_infosUser INTO v_rqt;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE c_infosUser;
      RETURN ;
    END;
  END;
```

I tried to use the method "SUM" and "DBMS_SPACE" but I can not properly use it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: how to check space used by a tablespace when no dba privs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476780/oracle-how-to-check-space-used-by-a-tablespace-when-no-dba-privs)

Comment: Any reason for using `plsql` for such requirement. It can be done by a simple sql statement as well.

Comment: What exactly have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: I tried select *,
sum(BYTES) BYTES
from... but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Users consume space for two things: tables and indexes. The usage is tracked in segments. There are two data dictionary views for this: `USER_SEGMENTS`, which shows the consumption of the connected user, and `DBA_SEGMENTS`, which shows the consumption of all users and requires a higher level of privileged access. (Segments is one of the subset of data dictionary views which does not have a `ALL_` version.)

The simplest version of the query would be:

```
select sum(bytes) as tot_segment_size
from dba_segments
where owner = 'WHOEVER';
```

The view has various other columns which you might want to use. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-7BF4F8C7-1917-4532-B048-C044E17A1754.htm#REFRN23243).

If you really want to wrap that query in a function you will need to the appropriate privileges on the data dictionary view (or the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY role) granted to your user **directly** i.e. not through a role.